# Configuring IIS 7.5 to be FIPS 140.2 compliant

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, tls, fips-140-2

I need to configure IIS 7.5 (Server 2008 R2) to be FIPS 140.2 compliant.

Specifically, this involves disabling all SSL protocols other than TLS 1.0.

I have set the following registry keys:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server
```

to Enabled(DWORD) = 0 as per [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187498), but [SSL Labs' checker](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssldb/index.html) says "SSL 2.0+ Upgrade Support" is enabled. (Everything other than that and TLS 1.0 is not available, so we're getting somewhere). It also says "FIPS ready - no" - presumably because SSL 2.0+ Upgrade Support is still enabled.

[serversniff.net](http://www.serversniff.net/sslcheck.php) says SSL 2.0 is turned off, and doesn't say anything about SSL 2.0+ Upgrade Support. Could this be an anomaly with SSL Labs' checker?

Comment: it might be easiest to contact Ivan (the SSL Labs developer) to figure out what exactly that means. Based on the following link, I have a feeling it is because IIS is throwing a 500 error when a SSLv2 connection is attempted, but not sure. http://blog.ivanristic.com/2009/08/improved-sslv2-detection-in-ssl-labs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the server supports SSLv2 handshake, even though it may
not support SSLv2 itself. Essentially it's an optimization. Instead of
a client first requesting SSLv2 (with a SSLv2 handshake) and failing
(if the server does not support it), then having to request SSLv3 or
better (with a SSLv3 handshake), the client can use the SSLv2
handshake to indicate support for newer protocols.

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20100629171623.43012oj4b2hgrzi8%40webmail.mxes.net&forum_name=ssllabs-discuss

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm that it is an issue with the SSL Labs Checker by changing the configuration in your browser to only accept SSL 2.0. If you can connect to your site, then SSL 2.0 is still enabled. Otherwise, it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

A company called Nartac software makes a free [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx) configuration tool that can be used to enable/disable protocols and cipher suites in IIS on Windows 2003, 2008 and 2012. It also comes with templates for configuring IIS to be FIPS 140.2 compliant, integrates with the [Qualys SSL](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) site analyzer for testing public urls, and has a list of other validation tools that can be used to validate internal sites.