# SSL/TLS Cipher Priority

Tags: tls, pci-dss, ssl, fips-140-2

I am working on trying to make sense of what is required for both PCI DSS compliance as well as FIPS compliance in relation to SSL/TLS cipher suites.  I have been reading the guide [here](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ssl/fips-ssl-ciphersuites.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  However, I have not been able to find anything that states what order or priority I should list the ciphers in.  I can see which ones I need to use and disable, but I assume that there is a priority that should be followed for them as well.  This is primarily for Windows servers and then later I would look at performing the same to Linux servers running Apache.

Comment: Check out https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx for a tool that will help you configure IIS to be PCI or FIPS compliant. From related question: http://serverfault.com/a/624857/33095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of Windows/IIS. In 2003 (IIS 6) and earlier, this can't be done. You can only enable/disable ciphers. In Windows 2008 (IIS 7) and later, you can do this through a GPO (if you're domain joined, and I'm guessing this server isn't if it's PCI compliant).

More info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766285(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the info and the link.  Do you know what order I should put them in?

Comment: If PCI doesn't recommend a particular priority (and I believe Shane is correct when he says they don't below), then I wouldn't worry about it. The DSS spec is so airtight as it is, you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you assume that there's a priority needed?

No compliance standard that I've ever heard of has recommended a specific priority; after all, if a cipher's insecure, it should be turned off instead of just de-prioritized.

That said, preferring RC4 over CBC-constructed ciphers might be wise until TLS 1.1 is widely deployed; see [CVE-2011-3389](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-3389).